# How to move / view pictures on Window PC

Tags: hard-drive

I have this HD sitting around for a couple of years now that has some pictures of the family I want off. I can see the addition drive. I am just not sure what to commands or tools to use from here. Pretty much a Ubuntu Noob that needs help.

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63  1441198079   720599008+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2      1441198080  1465145343    11973632    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Don't you see the disc on Nautilus? Or other file browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to open it up with Nautilus (the file browser). It should be listed under Computer, on the left side, or on your desktop. It will probably be named something like 100GB Filesystem.

The commands to mount the drive, if it isn't automatically, would be (replace $username$ with your username):

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/$username$/mydrive
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/$username$/mydrive
```

Then all of your files would be viewable at /media/$username$/mydrive